# Issue with linked lists and inheritance

Tags: java, object, inheritance, linked-list

Create an object from the child class and assign to a variable named theenemy

Create a second object from the child class and assign to a variable named enlink2

Call the inherited 'set' method of the first object and pass it the reference to the second object

Call the inherited 'set' method of the second object and pass it the reference to the first object

```
public class ALink {

private ALink next;

public void setNext(ALink x) {

next = x;

  }

public ALink getNext (  ) {

return next;

    }

 }

public class Zombie extends ALink  {

private int attackmode;

public void set_attackmode(int  am) {

attackmode = am;

 }

public int get_attackmode (  ) {

return attackmode;

   }

}
```

Here is my input

```
Zombie theenemy = new Zombie();

Zombie enlink2 = new Zombie();

theenemy.setNext(enlink2);

enlink2.setNext(theenemy);
```

Am getting an unexpected identifier error, not sure where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Private variables of parent class are not part of sub classes. Change the access specifier of next in ALink, say protected, then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve here but your code snippet is working for me without any issue. At which line are you getting error?

I tried your code with one extra Sysout statement and getting proper output:

```
    public class ALink {
    private ALink next;

    public void setNext(ALink x) {
        next = x;
        System.out.println("setNext is  called for " + x.getClass().getName());
    }

    public ALink getNext() {

        return next;

    }
}

public class Zombie extends ALink {

    private int attackmode;

    public void set_attackmode(int am) {
        attackmode = am;
    }

    public int get_attackmode() {
        return attackmode;
    }

}

public class TestZombie {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Zombie theenemy = new Zombie();

        Zombie enlink2 = new Zombie();

        theenemy.setNext(enlink2);

        enlink2.setNext(theenemy);
    }
}
```

Getting following output:

```
setNext is  called for Zombie
setNext is  called for Zombie
```

Comment: I also input it into Netbeans and there were no errors. However, this is through my comp sci professor's website, and it's complaining about an unexpected identifier when I submit it.